# How to redirect requests to the site to the "public" folder with apache2?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, lamp

My site is located to the `/var/www/html/qwerty/public` folder. I need the request at the root address `localhost/qwerty` to open the main page of the site with the same address. That is, the `/var/www/html/qwerty/public/index.php` file should open, and static files are also opened by appropriate requests. For example, the request `localhost/qwerty/123.jpg` should open the `/var/www/html/qwerty/public/123.jpg` file. And still in the address line there should be the same address (`localhost/qwerty/123.jpg`), without including the `public` folder.

At this time, when requesting `localhost/qwerty`, the structure of folders is displayed. When pressing the `public` folder, the main page opens, and `localhost/qwerty/public` on the address line.

[image]

I need the main page to open. In addition, access to the `/var/www/html/qwerty` folder should be forbidden, where the core files will be located.

I read several posts on this topic, and made the settings, but it opens the folder tree instead of the main page. This is my first day of work with configuring the apache2 server.
The structure of folders and files is as follows:

```
|--/var/www/html
|  |--index.html
|  |--qwerty
|  |  |--.htaccess
|  |  |--public
|  |  |  |--index.php
```

`/var/www/html/qwerty/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/qwerty.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/qwerty/public
    ServerName qwerty

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The following commands were also used:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

```
sudo a2ensite qwerty
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you're using `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/qwerty/public` then `/qwerty/` will not be part of your URL and your URLs will be like: `localhost/123.jpg`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, the problem is solved